# Decrease in JSON to SQL import time - Why?

Tags: sql, json, sqlite

So I'm importing a JSON-file to a SQLite database. At first, I imported the JSON-objects to a table that looked kinda like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    column1 STRING,
    column2 STRING,
    column3 STRING,
    column1 STRING,
    column2 INT,
    column3 STRING,
);
```

For some reason, it took a loooong time for the program to import the data (the JSON-file was pretty large), so I was looking into my options on decreasing the import time. I added constraints on the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    column1 NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    column2 NOT NULL,
    column2 NULL,
    column2 TEXT NULL,
    column3 INT NOT NULL,
    column2 NOT NULL,
);
```

And suddenly, it took almost half the time to import the JSON. My question then is why did the import time improve? Aren't constraints just suppose to keep the database "safe" or define some business logic?

Comment: How were you inserting the rows? SQLite doesn't treat VARCHAR(10) any different than it treats STRING. Also UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY is redundant as the PRIMARY KEY is already UNIQUE. And NOT NULL only causes it to check that the column value is not NULL before permitting the insert to succeed. None of those explain your reported difference.

Comment: @DanD. Yeah, you're right, so I removed the VARCHAR (updated question, also added all column types). Still, it still improves the import time by adding the NOT NULL etc. constraints.

Comment: @DanD. I'm doing the exakt same row insert syntax for both examples

Comment: I don't think datatype `STRING` exists in Sqlite. And you'll have a hard time creating repeating column names. So we have to say something about the difference between codes, neither of which will run.

Answer (score 0):

If no one has a better answer, my guess is that the row is taking up less space, and that makes it easier to insert and look up for duplicates in the database